# How to quit script when Telebot sees a new message

Tags: python, telegram

I have two python scripts which I run using a batch script. Once one script is executed, the next script starts. I need one of the scripts, the Telebot script, to quit after recording a message in a .json file. Unfortunately, while the message does get recorded, I am having trouble quitting the script, meaning my second python file is not being executed.

```
import telebot
import json
import os
import sys
import time


with open('JSON_file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


group_chat_id = 'CHAT_ID_HERE'


hbot = telebot.TeleBot('BOT_TOKEN_HERE')

hbot.send_photo(chat_id = group_chat_id, caption = data, photo = open('C:/Users/.../image.jpg', 'rb'))

temp = ""
@hbot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def get_input(message):
    global temp
    message_str = str(message.text)
    message_str = message_str.strip()
    temp = message_str
    print(temp)
    

    with open('JSON_file.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(temp, json_file)


    hbot.stop_polling()
   
    if temp != "":
        quit()
    

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hbot.polling()
```

I run the code(s) using an executable .bat file, however, the code below does not quit once a message is received. Does anyone know why the quit() command does not stop my code?

Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using sys.exit instead of quit: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit

> In python, we have an in-built quit() function which is used to exit a python program. When it encounters the quit() function in the system, it terminates the execution of the program completely.

> It should not be used in production code and this function should only be used in the interpreter.

Source: https://pythonguides.com/python-exit-command/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The script now closes, however, theres a 20 second gap between receiving the message and closing. Do you know how to shorten this gap?

Comment: @Clarence_Plopper i'd recommend printing something before sys.exit, because sys.exit happens instantly so something else in your code probably takes 20s until it reaches sys.exit. If the code is still the same i could imagine `hbot.stop_polling()` taking these 20s. Just use print statements to figure out where the 20s get lost